# Informatica, [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified error when connecting to Exasol database

Tags: odbc, informatica, exasolution, exasol

I am trying to connect to Exasol database from Informatica where I want to do some read and write operations but getting below error when running the session.
I have added driver details in ODBC Data Source Administrator.

*Message Code: CMN_1022
Message: Database driver error...
CMN_1022 [
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
Database driver error...
Function Name : Connect
Database driver error...
Function Name : Connect
Database Error: Failed to connect to database using user [User_Name] and connection string [Connection_String].]*

Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Below are screenshot of USER DSN and SYS DSN entries.
I tested the connection and showed successful.

[User DSN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdRig.png)
[Sys DSN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y0OV.png)

Comment: Pls make sure, if server is on UNIX/LINUX, the connection string in .odbc.ini file and in informatica are identical (its case sensitive), if server is on Windows, pls make sure you added the entry in correct version 32/64 and mention connection string same as the odbc  admin.

Comment: Thank you for your input.. Server is on Windows. I have made the entries in both 32/64 bit ODBC Data Sources as admin, still getting the same error.

Comment: thx for the screenshots. I am not 100% sure, but informatica prefers data direct ODBC driver. Do you have data direct for ExaSol ? Also can you pls remove space from the DSN name - make it like 'ExaSol_Driver'?

Comment: Informatica don't have data direct for Exasol as of now and suggests to use drivers direclty from Exasol.
I will change the DSN name and will let you know. Thank You.